# How to manipulate a string so I can make implicit multiplication explicit in a math expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to manipulate a string like "...4+3(4-2)-...." to become "...4+3*(4-2)-....", but of course it should recognize **any number**, d,  followed by a '(' and change it to 'd*('. And I also want to change ')(' to ')*(' at the same time if possible. Would nice if there is a possibility to add support for constants like pi or e too.

For now, I just do it this stupid way:

```
private function make_implicit_multiplication_explicit($string)
{
    $i=1;
    if(strlen($string)>1)
    {
        while(($i=strpos($string,"(",$i))!==false)
        {
            if(strpos("0123456789",substr($string,$i-1,1))) 
            {
                $string=substr_replace($string,"*(",$i,1);
                $i++;
            }
            $i++;
        }

        $string=str_replace(")(",")*(",$string);
    }        
    return $string;
 }
```

But I Believe this could be done much nicer with preg_replace or some other regex function? But those manuals are really cumbersome to grasp, I think.

Comment: Do you have anything against regular expressions?

Comment: @sectus Well they are hard to master and I do want to learn, thats why I asked the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start by what you are looking for:

- either of the following: (`(a|b)` will match either `a` or `b`)

  - any number, `\d`
  - the character `)`: `\)`
- followed by `(`: `\(`

Which creates this pattern: `(\d|\))\(`. But since you want to modify the string and keep both parts, you can group the `\(` which results in `(\()` making it worse to read but better to handle.

Now everything left is to tell how to rearrange, which is simple: `\\1*\\2`, leaving you with code like this

```
$regex = "/(\d|\))(\()/";
$replace = "\\1*\\2";
$new = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $test);
```

To see that the pattern actually matches all cases, see [this example](http://regex101.com/r/gV5oU0/1).

Comment: Thanks! I Tried this, and it works. Thanks to your explaining I also think I understand it even if thoose patterns are really hypnotizing. :)

Comment: @NickSick You're welcome. The need to escape `(`/`)` doesn't make this easy to read, true, but it is a simple logic. However, there is more advanced logic such as posted by hwnd or Avinash Raj. Demonstrating quite well that when using regex, all roads lead to Rome

Comment: Since i also wanted support for constants, functions and variables I finally(?) came to this $regex="/((?<![a-zA-Z_])\d)(\(|[a-zA-Z_])|(\))(\()|(\))(\d)/" and $replace="\\1\\3\\5*\\2\\4\\6" making "3(3+5)(3-4)2+3x+3int(4.5)+3pi" to "3*(3+5)*(3-4)*2+3*x+3*int(4.5)+3*pi"

Answer (score 4):

To recognize any number followed by a `(` **OR** a combination of a `)(` and place an asterisk in between them, you can use a combination of [lookaround](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookaround) assertions.

```
echo preg_replace("/

         (?<=[0-9)])   # look behind to see if there is: '0' to '9', ')'
         (?=\()        # look ahead to see if there is: '('

         /x", '*', '(4+3(4-2)-3)(2+3)');
```

The [Positive Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) asserts that what precedes is either a number or right parentheses. While the [Positive Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) asserts that the preceding characters are followed by a left parentheses.

Another option is to use the `\K` escape sequence in replace of the Lookbehind. `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included ( *throws away everything that it has matched up to that point.* )

```
echo preg_replace("/

         [0-9)]   # any character of: '0' to '9', ')'
          \K      # resets the starting point of the reported match
          (?=\()  # look ahead to see if there is: '('

         /x", '*', '(4+3(4-2)-3)(2+3)');
```

Comment: Thanks, for this one too! Nice to see so many different soloutions.

Comment: @NickSick we could post many possible solutions in PCRE regex type of questions.

Comment: Btw thanks for the explanation of `\K`, wasted more time than I'm willing to admit researching what it means when I saw your post

Answer (score 3):

Your php code should be,

```
<?php
$mystring = "4+3(4-2)-(5)(3)";
$regex = '~\d+\K\(~';
$replacement = "*(";
$str = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $mystring);
$regex1 = '~\)\K\(~';
$replacement1 = "*(";
echo preg_replace($regex1, $replacement1, $str);
?> //=>  4+3*(4-2)-(5)*(3)
```

**Explanation:**

- `~\d+\K\(~` this  would match the one or more numbers followed by a `(`. Because of \K it excludes the \d+
- Again it replaces the matched part with `*(` which in turn produces `3*(` and the result was stored in another variable.
- `\)\K\(` Matches `)(` and excludes the first `)`. This would be replaced by `*(` which in turn produces `)*(`

[DEMO 1](http://regex101.com/r/tN7aB7/1)

[DEMO 2](http://regex101.com/r/tN7aB7/2)

Answer (score 0):

Silly method :^ )

```
$value = '4+3(4-2)(1+2)';

$search = ['1(', '2(', '3(', '4(', '5(', '6(', '7(', '8(', '9(', '0(', ')('];
$replace = ['1*(', '2*(', '3*(', '4*(', '5*(', '6*(', '7*(', '8*(', '9*(', '0*(', ')*('];

echo str_replace($search, $replace, $value);
```